# How can I manually determine device orientation if I have restricted orientation in my app?

Tags: ios, swift, orientation

I have restricted fixed device orientation in my app to portrait only. However just like Instagram I have a camera function and I need to get the current orientation in swift, but the orientation always displays as portrait. Is there a way to use the gyroscope to manually get the orientation?

Answer (score 1):

UIDevice can tell you the orientation even if you do not support auto rotation.  I use this to handle rotation in only one view controller:

```
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        UIDevice.current.beginGeneratingDeviceOrientationNotifications()
        NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(orientationChanged), name: NSNotification.Name.UIDeviceOrientationDidChange, object: nil)
    }

    deinit {
        UIDevice.current.endGeneratingDeviceOrientationNotifications()
        NotificationCenter.default.removeObserver(self)
    }

    @objc private func orientationChanged(_ notification: Foundation.Notification) {
        currentOrientation = UIDevice.current.orientation
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

In Swift 2.3, you can use the following code to set the orientation of the AVCaptureDeviceInput (or replace with your own functionality).

I have use this code in https://github.com/ytakzk/Fusuma -> FSCameraView.swift

```
import CoreMotion


//var videoInput: AVCaptureDeviceInput?
let motionManager = CMMotionManager()

if motionManager.gyroAvailable {
    motionManager.deviceMotionUpdateInterval = 0.2;
    motionManager.startDeviceMotionUpdates()

    motionManager.gyroUpdateInterval = 1
            motionManager.startDeviceMotionUpdatesToQueue(NSOperationQueue.currentQueue()!) {
        (data: CMDeviceMotion?, error:NSError?) in

        if let videoConnection = self.imageOutput?.connectionWithMediaType(AVMediaTypeVideo) {
            if (data?.gravity.x)! > -0.6 && (data?.gravity.x)! < 0.6 {
                if (data?.gravity.y)! < 0.4 {
                    videoConnection.videoOrientation = .Portrait
                } else {
                    videoConnection.videoOrientation = .PortraitUpsideDown
                }
            } else {
                if (data?.gravity.x)! < 0 {
                    videoConnection.videoOrientation = .LandscapeRight
                } else {
                    videoConnection.videoOrientation = .LandscapeLeft
                }
            }
        }
        //print(data?.gravity.x)
        //print(data?.gravity.y)
        //print(data?.gravity.z)
    }
}
```